# Model property, collection list is empty upon post to controller, potental issues with MVC with large size string list?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying post a simple list within a model back to the controller. its rendered correctly but on post its always empty. I noticed when I use @Html.Hidden for the id and name are different for instance id becomes `TestExceptionDisplay_[0]__Exception` and name becomes `TestExceptionDisplay[0].Exception`. So I use an input type and try to make the  way it likes to render but it does not work. I tried partial view, editor templates, nothing seems to work. TestException Display is a very simple list of an object called  `public List<RunLogEntryTestExceptionDisplay> TestExceptionDisplay { get; set; }`

```
public class RunLogEntryTestExceptionDisplay
{
    public string Exception { get; set; }
}
```

Snippet in the view which uses a for loop to render list, list is rendered fine but on post TestExceptionDisplay is NULL always:

```
@if (Model.TestExceptionDisplay != null)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < Model.TestExceptionDisplay.Count; i++)
    {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Model.TestExceptionDisplay[i].Exception
            @*@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.TestExceptionDisplay[i].Exception)*@
            <input  name="RunLogEntry.TestExceptionDisplay_[@i]__Exception" type="hidden" value="@Model.TestExceptionDisplay[i].Exception" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    }
}
```

OR this does not even work with editor templates upon post

```
  @if (Model.TestExceptionDisplay != null)
                {

                    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.TestExceptionDisplay)

                }
```

Editor Template in Shared\EditorTemplates with the exact name of RunLogEntryTestExceptionDisplay

```
@model RunLog.Domain.Entities.RunLogEntryTestExceptionDisplay
<div>
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Exception)
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Exception)
</div>
```

Rendered HTML looks like below, I did not copy the entire list, PLEASE NOT THAT THE ID AND NAME SEEM TO RENDER IN A DIFFERENT NAMING CONVENTION. IT HAPPENS in both cases, if I use an editor template or a for loop. thanks

```
 <input id="TestExceptionDisplay_9__Exception" name="TestExceptionDisplay[9].Exception" type="hidden" value="&quot;1404 TestException - Parameters:Unable to calculate result, assay is not calibrated for Assay Number (135), Assay Version (5), Track (1), Lane (2), and Reagent Lot Number (26600LI06)&quot;" />
```

[image: Debugg-View]

Complete View:

```
   @model RunLog.Domain.Entities.RunLogEntry
    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Create";
        Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";

    }
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/errorCode.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/testexception.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/runLogEntry.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var runlogListErrorsUrl = '@Url.Action("ListErrorCodes", "RunLogEntry")';


    </script>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Enter a new Run Log Entry</legend>
        @using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "RunLogEntry", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
        {
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
            <div class="exception">@(ViewBag.ErrorMessage)</div>
            <div class="bodyContent">
                <span class="leftContent">Load List File (Select): </span><span class="rightContent">
                    <input type="file" name="file" id="file1" style="width: 500px" />
                </span>
            </div>
                               if (Model.LoadListStoredFileName != null)
                               {
            <div class="bodyContent">
                <span class="leftContent">Attached Load List: </span><span class="rightContent">
                    @Html.ActionLink(Model.LoadListFileName, "Download", new { @file = Model.LoadListStoredFileName })
                </span>
            </div>
                               }
            <div class="bodyContent">
                <span class="leftContent">Output File (Select): </span><span class="rightContent">
                    <input type="file" name="file" id="file2" style="width: 500px" />
                </span>
            </div>
                               if (Model.OutputStoredFileName != null)
                               {
            <div class="bodyContent">
                <span class="leftContent">Attached Output: </span><span class="rightContent">
                    @Html.ActionLink(Model.OutputFileName, "Download", new { @file = Model.OutputStoredFileName })
                </span>
            </div>
                               }
            <div class="bodyContent">
                <span class="leftContent">Import Files: </span>
                <button name="submit" class="art-button" type="submit" value="Upload" style="width: 100px">
                    Upload</button>
                <button name="submit" class="art-button" type="submit" value="Remove" style="width: 100px">
                    Remove</button>
            </div>
            <div class="bodyContent">
                <span class="leftContent">
                    @Html.Label("Operator")
                </span><span class="rightContent">
                    @Html.DropDownList("OperatorID", String.Empty)
                </span>
            </div>
            <div class="bodyContent">
                <span class="leftContent">
                    @Html.Label("Run ID")
                </span><span class="rightContent">[Generated] </span>
            </div>
            <div class="bodyContent">
                <span class="leftContent">
                    @Html.Label("Run Start Date / Time")
                </span><span class="rightContent">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.RunDate)
                    &nbsp;
                    @Html.DropDownList("Hour", ListHelpers.HourList())
                    :
                    @Html.DropDownList("Minute", ListHelpers.Minute15List())
                    &nbsp;
                    @Html.DropDownList("AMPM", ListHelpers.AMPMList())
                </span>
            </div>
            <div class="bodyContent">
                <span class="leftContent">
                    @Html.Label("System")
                </span><span class="rightContent">
                    @Html.DropDownList("SystemID", String.Empty)
                </span>
            </div>
            <div class="bodyContent">
                <span class="leftContent">
                    @Html.Label("Run Type")
                </span><span class="rightContent">
                    @Html.DropDownList("RunTypeID", String.Empty)
                </span>
            </div>
            <div class="bodyContent">
                <span class="leftContent">
                    @Html.Label("Run Description")
                </span><span class="rightContent">
                    @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.RunDescription, new { style = "width: 600px; height=30px" })
                </span>
            </div>
            <div class="bodyContent">
                <span class="leftContent">
                    @Html.Label("Assay Performance Issues")
                </span><span class="rightContent">
                    @Html.DropDownList("AssayPerformanceIssues1", ListHelpers.YesNoList())
                </span>
            </div>
            <div class="bodyContent">
                <span class="leftContent">
                    @Html.Label("Tests/Cycles Requested")
                </span><span class="rightContent">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SPTestsRequested)
                </span>
            </div>
            <div class="bodyContent">
                <span class="leftContent">
                    @Html.Label("Tests/Cycles Completed")
                </span><span class="rightContent">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SPTestsCompleted)
                </span>
            </div>
            <div class="bodyContent">
                <span class="leftContent">
                    @Html.Label("Run Status")
                </span><span class="rightContent">
                    @Html.DropDownList("RunStatusID", String.Empty)
                </span>
            </div>
            <div class="bodyContent">
                <span class="leftContent">
                    @Html.Label("Assay")
                </span><span class="rightContent">
                    @Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.SelectedAssayIDs, new MultiSelectList(RunLog.Domain.Lists.GlobalList.AssayListItems(), "ID", "Name", Model.SelectedAssayIDs))
                </span>
            </div>
            <div class="bodyContent">
                <span class="leftContent">
                    @Html.Label("Error Code")
                </span><span class="rightContent"><span id="ChildDialogLink" class="treeViewLink">Click
                    here to Select Error Codes</span>
                    <br />
                    <span id="ErrorCodeDisplay" style="cursor: pointer; text-decoration: underline;">@(Model.ErrorDescription)</span>
                    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ErrorDescription)
                </span>
            </div>

            <div class="bodyContent">
                <span class="leftContent">
                    @Html.Label("Test Exceptions")
                </span><span class="rightContent"><span id="TestExceptionChildDialogLink" class="treeViewLink">
                    Click here to View Test Exceptions</span>
                    <br />
                    <span id="TestExceptionDisplayy"></span></span>
            </div>
            <div id="testExceptiontreeview" title="Dialog Title" style="font-size: 10px; font-weight: normal;
                overflow: scroll; width: 800px; height: 450px;">
                <div id="testExceptions">
                </div>
                <div id="inputTestExceptions">
                    <table class="grid" style="width: 450px; margin: 3px 3px 3px 3px;">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>
                                    Exception String
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    Comment
                                </th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        @* @{var index = 0;}*@
                        @if (Model.TestExceptionDisplay != null)
                        {
                            for (var i = 0; i < Model.TestExceptionDisplay.Count; i++)
                            {
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    @Model.TestExceptionDisplay[i].Exception
                                    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.TestExceptionDisplay[i].Exception)
                                </td>
                            </tr>

                            }
                        }
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="bodyContent">
                <span class="leftContent">
                    @Html.Label("Service Entry Request")
                </span><span class="rightContent">
                    @Html.DropDownList("ServiceRequest", ListHelpers.YesNoList())
                </span>
            </div>
            <div class="bodyContent">
                <span class="leftContent">
                    @Html.Label("Problem Description")
                </span><span class="rightContent">
                    @Html.TextArea("ProblemDescription", new { style = "width: 600px; height: 30px" })
                </span>
            </div>
            <p>
                <input id="LogType" type="hidden" value="Run" />
                <input id="ID" type="hidden" value="0" />
                @if (Model.ExitCode == "1")
                {
                    @Html.Hidden("ExitCode", Model.ExitCode)
                }
                else
                {
                    <input id="ExitCode" type="hidden" value='0' />
                }
            </p>

            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.MaxReplicateId)
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.MinReplicateId)
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.OutputFileName)
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.OutputStoredFileName)
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.LoadListFileName)
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.LoadListStoredFileName)
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.MinTestCompletionDate)
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.MaxTestCompletionDate)

            <div class="bodyContent">
                <span class="leftContent"></span><span class="rightContent">
                    <button name="submit" class="art-button" type="submit" value="Create">
                        Create</button></span>
            </div>
        }
    </fieldset>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/exitCode.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/exitCode.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <div id="treeview" title="Dialog Title" style="font-size: 10px; font-weight: normal;
        overflow: scroll; width: 800px; height: 450px;">
        <div id="errorCodes">
            @Html.RenderTree(CacheHelper.ErrorCodes(), ec => ec.Name, ec => ec.Children.ToList(), ec => (ec.ID).ToString(), null, "e")
        </div>
        <div id="inputReps" style="display: none;">
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I don't see an Html.BeginForm(), are your input tags inside a form?

Comment: Yes, If you look at the complete view I posted, I do have this @using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "RunLogEntry", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" })) .

Comment: You have a lot going on there.  Have you tried reducing the complexity of the view to see if the problem goes away?  Another thing, do you have any custom model binders?  If so, it may be bypassing the standard behavior.  Also, you must create an empty instance of the List in your models constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you expecting the list in the model you receive to be populated?

The model on POST is populated only with data from the form - MVC creates a new instance of your model class and populates the fields it can match up.

Because of this, the stock way of making sure your lists are populated is to have a helper method which populates them. You can then call this from either the original `Get` or the `Post` method to repopulate the lists.

The only time you'd expect to get a list populated in your model by PMV on postback is when the details to rebuild the list are available in form elements.

It's possible I've missed it in your reams of code but I can't see you doing that anywhere.

Comment: So the process flow is users upload a file from page, hit a upload button on this page, my controller parses out the attached file, populates a bunch of fields including this list. then it renders the view again. when users verify and fill out more fields and click the save button this entire record will be saved so thats why i need this list. once its working i expcect to add a comment textarea for each exception so they could add some text. other non list hidden fields are posted back easily. Since the list is rendered on the view/form, why would it be lost upon post? thanks

Comment: The form elements before post back has the entire list,confirmed in view source with the correct index starting at 0. So the list is there in the form elemenent, would i need to do something else to populate it, please give an example, im just stuck with this for a long time now. thanks

Comment: I didn't see where you were outputting that, my mistake. In this case, it looks like because you're iterating the list yourself, the editors being generated aren't being mapped back to the list items correctly - have a look in the generated HTML, what do the actual input fields look like. The easiest way around this is with a custom editor template. [Example here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9800353/156755)

Comment: This is an item from the list in the generated HTML. <input id="TestExceptionDisplay_18__Exception" name="TestExceptionDisplay[18].Exception" type="hidden" value="&quot;1007 TestException - Parameters:Unable to process test, activated read failure&quot;" />
I have tried editor templates, partial view. it does not work.

Comment: I just tried with Editor templates and the same HTML as above is rendered

Comment: Ok, then you need to have a look at what's happening inside the ModelBinder... Enable [Framework source code stepping](http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2010/07/04/stepping-into-asp-net-mvc-source-code-with-visual-studio-debugger.aspx) and add some breakpoints around the `ModelBinder` (Have a look inside `System.Web.ModelBinding` specifically at the `ModelBinders` collection). You could also try [creating your own model binder](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8086989/156755) and see what it's being passed

Comment: Thanks for all your help. I just dont have enough time now to create a custom model binder just because a list post which would normally work is not working now. I spend so much time on this now, Now I will attemopt a quick dirty way by doing some string manipulation and hidden fields. it seem to work for non list variables. thanks again

Comment: No worries, I understand completely. It's probably something obvious but I can't see what it is at a glance - perhaps someone else can. Leave the Q open just in case. Good luck

Comment: So it works both with an editor template or a for loop. I had list beging rendered in a div and as a jquery modal box placed in a JS file which was taking it out of the DOM.  wow what a mistake i made, thanks for your help.

Comment: Glad you got it fixed. Hopefully we'll see you around more on SO

Answer (score 1):

You should initialize your `list` in  your first method, then pass to `post` method.

Comment: did you mean I have to intialize the list in the view when its been rendered before post?

Comment: @tammy - You should instantiate a new (empty) instance of your List in your models constructor.

Comment: We do not have a model constructor, just properties. I even tried editor templates, maybe MVC does not work with large text size lists?

Comment: this is how a list item is rendered in the HTML <input class="text-box single-line" id="TestExceptionDisplay_8__Exception" name="TestExceptionDisplay[8].Exception" type="text" value="&quot;1008 TestException - Parameters:Unable to process test, final read failure.&quot;" />

Comment: @tammy - that's the point... You SHOULD have a constructor in your models, and it SHOULD new up a new instance of the List class.  The fact you don't have one is probably what your problem is.  The model binder does not create a new instance of nested classes.